# Linux - User expiration date in hours

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am setting the expiration date of my linux users account using the command below:

```
chage -E '2017-04-07' username
```

However I can only block the user using dates, and when the day occurs the user is already blocked.

Would you like to have the account expire in 24hrs?

Tks!

Comment: It would be more on topic on AskUbuntu or Unix&Linux since it does not involve programs. But `man shadow` is enough: the account expiration date field is *The date of expiration of the account, expressed as the number of days since Jan 1, 1970*. Whatever you do, the system has only a day granularity. Use FreeBSD if you want login expiration date in seconds ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the 'chage' since it require specifying a date. If you want to inactivate a user after few minutes, use following

```
adduser username_here && sleep 600 && usermod --lock username_here
```

OR

```
adduser username_here
echo usermod --lock username_here | at now + 10 minutes
```

Comment: Looks like you are using ubuntu, install 'at' by sudo apt-get install at

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!